# Custom Calendar in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, calendar

Does anyone know how to create such a calendar. Or give advice where to dig. I will be glad for any help. (React.js project)

[image: Custom Calendar in JavaScript]

Comment: Here are a collection of examples that may be able to help you get started/find some inspiration! https://reactjsexample.com/tag/calendar/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found this solution and Also used I have one time this type of calendar I have shown the following calendar helps you

codepen.io/sebpearce/pen/JpMbLK

I hope this reference helps you and check this

- https://year-calendar.github.io/js-year-calendar/docs/index.html
- Also you find this solution in sandbox code or codepen and search Calendar or search Goole in Linear Calendar.